# Laravel Project table default unit

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have got a Laravel Projetk where I have a table (time, track, length). If a user make a input I want that per default der is "km"(length) or "min"(time), so that the user only has to tipe a number but in the table stands a unit next to the number.

```
            $table->string('track', 150);
```

Thats how i put numbers in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive the best way is convert the data.

1. Using mask in the view
2. Convert to persist um database